# NullPointerException / NPE Caused by addTextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fatal-error, null-pointer

I'm attempting to set a listener to detect if the text in my mAttendeesList has changed using the following:

```
EditEventView.mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);
```

However mAttendeesList continually equals null...

I've implemented it as follows:

### EditEventActivity.java

```
 private void initChangeListeners() {
        if (mViewListener == null) {
          mViewListener = new RecipientTextWatcher(mView, mViewListener);
        }
        EditEventView.mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);

    }
```

### EditEventView.java

...

```
static MultiAutoCompleteTextView mAttendeesList;
```

...

```
private boolean fillModelFromUI() {
```

...

```
 if (mAttendeesList != null) {
```

...

However it always returns null and I am unsure why.

Any suggestions / pointers are greatly appreciated.

### Edit (in response to first answer):

```
   private void initChangeListeners() {

        clearChangeListeners();
        if (mViewListener == null) {
          mViewListener = new RecipientTextWatcher(mAttendeesList, mViewListener);
        }

        EditEventView mEditEventView = new EditEventView(EditEventActivity.this, mAttendeesList, mDone, false, false);
        EditEventView.mAttendeesList.addTextChangedListener(mViewListener);

    }
        private void clearChangeListeners() {

             if (mViewListener != null) {

        mView.removeTextChangedListener(mViewListener);       
    }
             }
```

### Edit Result:

ERROR:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 17:37:17.887: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.calendar.event.EditEventView.<init>(EditEventView.java:851)
01-28 17:37:17.887: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.calendar.event.EditEventActivity.initChangeListeners(EditEventActivity.java:183)
01-28 17:37:17.887: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.calendar.event.EditEventActivity.onCreate(EditEventActivity.java:161)
```

ERROR OCCURS AT:

```
EditEventView 851: mAttendeesListView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduling_attendee_list);
EditEventActivity 183: EditEventView mEditEventView = new EditEventView(EditEventActivity.this, mAttendeesList, mDone, false, false);
EditEventActivity 161: initChangeListeners();
```

### More Info:

https://www.zerobin.net/?2ce740738b028ed1#Q7JVl/DQXkMGqbYaYQ/XnXMX8pHLL3kbKHunLmkffqc=

Comment: Why the down vote? I'll gladly edit - if someone can point out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized your `EditEventView` object, and your `mAttendeesList` is initialized in its constructor. Therefore, if you do not initialize `EditEventView` (i.e. call its constructor) your `mAttendeesList` will be null.

You need to make sure that before you reference `EditEventView.mAttendeesList` (or any dynamic member of `EditEventView` for that matter) you create an instance of `EditEventView` class.

Comment: How might this be accomplished?

Comment: Something along the lines of  EditEventView  = new EditEventView(); 


?

Comment: Yup, `EditEventView mEditEventView = new EditEventView(...)` will create `mEditEventView` object which you can reference in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure what I've done wrong... I'm still getting a FATAL / NPE when using:
 
EditEventView mEditEventView = new EditEventView(EditEventActivity.this, mAttendeesList, mDone, false, false);
        

More Info Here: 

https://www.zerobin.net/?2ce740738b028ed1#Q7JVl/DQXkMGqbYaYQ/XnXMX8pHLL3kbKHunLmkffqc=